# Finding a volume of a solid using Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am suppose to find the volume of a solid using double integral for the following solid:
[image]

My friend got an answer of 4 while I got an answer of 20/3 . I wanted to know who is correct on this?

This is my work: [image]

Comment: Use $$\LaTeX$$.

Comment: The limits for $y$ in your second line are wrong so you are not correct (unless you were lucky).  Don't know if your friend is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Volume = $$\int \int \int dzdxdy = \int_{y=0}^{y=2} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} (4-y^2)dx dy = \int_{y=0}^{y=2}(4y - y^3)dy = 4 $$

Answer (score 0):

Limit on y should be $ lower\; limit \;Y=X \;to\; upper\; limit \;Y=2$ and then do calculation you will get right answer.

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates (not very good idea):
$$z = 4 - y^2 = 4 - r^2\sin^2\theta;$$
$$V = \int_0^4\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{4 - z}/\sin\theta}r \,dr\,d\theta\,dz = \cdots = 4.$$